# Integer compareTo() method, does it always return -1, 0 or 1?

Tags: java, integer, compareto

The [javadocs](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Integer.html#compareTo(java.lang.Integer)) for the method compareTo() of the Integer class are extremely vague:

> Returns: the value 0 if this Integer is equal to the argument Integer; a value less than 0 if this Integer is numerically less than the argument Integer; and a value greater than 0 if this Integer is numerically greater than the argument Integer (signed comparison)

The phrasing "a value less than 0" makes it seem like I can expect compareTo() to return all sort of negative integers (-1, -20, -9999, etc). Same for "a value greater than 0", it could really be anything above 0.

I noticed the method tends to return -1 and 1, however from the javadocs there is no guarantee that this behavior will be consistent. All I'm allowed to expected is an integer less than 0 or greater than 0, which could really be anything.

Does the function indeed always return -1, 0, or 1? Or does it occasionally return other values?

If it only returns -1, 0, and 1, why is that not clearly stated in the javadocs?

Example:

```
Integer myInteger = 8;
System.out.print(myInteger.compareTo(5));
// This prints 1
```

**EDIT:**

Interestingly, IntelliJ acts as if compareTo() always returns -1, 0, or 1. That is, if you have the following code:

```
public int myCompare(int x, int y){
    if(x == y){
        return 0;
    } else if(x < y){
        return -1;
    } else{
        return 1;
    }
}
```

IntelliJ will give the warning "Expression can be replaced with 'Integer.compare'", and recommend the method be changed to:

```
public int myCompare(int x, int y){
    return Integer.compare(x, y);
}
```

Comment: It's an abstraction for *greater than*, *equal* and *less than*… This method only compares two objects.

Comment: Regardless of what it actually does, there is no guarantee, so they can change it tomorrow morning. So don't rely on it. Rely on the Javadoc.

Comment: "why is that not clearly stated in the javadocs?" (i) to match the [specification](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Comparable.html) of `Comparable`; (ii) to allow future optimizations; ... BTW the *smaller* primitives do indeed return different values (implemented by subtracting both values, which would not correctly work with `int`)

Comment: The documentation says what you can rely on.  If you rely on anything beyond that, what you've got it unreliable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is (IMO) unlikely that they will change the implementation of `Integer`. However the spec for `Integer.compareTo` does not state that the result is -1, 0 or +1 ... so they >could< change it. And if they do, then your code that relied on it would break.

> So if I want to guarantee it returns -1, 0 or 1, I have to wrap it with a `Integer.signum()`?

Correct.  Or implement your own `Comparator` or `compareTo` method ... if that is viable.

If you are concerned about performance, there is a good chance that the JIT compiler will inline `signum(compareTo(anInteger))`.  It may even optimize away the redundant `signum` logic ...

> If it only returns -1, 0, and 1, why is that not clearly stated in the javadocs?

We can't speak for the people who wrote the spec.  However, I imagine that they didn't want to preclude the possibility of changing the implementation; e.g. for (hypothetical) performance reasons.

Comment: Interestingly, IntelliJ will suggest using Integer.compareTo() for code that returns -1, 0, or 1 from an integer comparison (see edit to original post). Is IntelliJ making a mistake here?

Answer (score 2):

`-1` and `1` are chosen for readability, convention and correctness.

For objects that are compared using an integer value, returning the difference of that value would seem to make for a simpler implementation, eg

```
int compareTo(MyClass that) {
    return myInt - that.myInt;
}
```

however [integer overflow](https://simple.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_overflow) can result in returning an incorrect result. Consider when `this.myInt` is a large positive number and `that.myInt` is a large negative number - the arithmetic result may be more than `Integer.MAX_VALUE` which would then roll around to be a *negative* number, which would be wrong.

Whatever the implementation, don't rely on anything but the contract - ie "any int" may be returned.

Comment: "Whatever the implementation, don't rely on anything but the contract - ie "any int" may be returned.".  So if I want to guarantee it returns -1, 0 or 1, I have to wrap it with a Integer.signum( )? It seems unnecessary to me - do we really expect the implementation of such a fundamental class to randomly change after decades of working a certain way?

Comment: @GuillaumeF. You cannot rely on the implementation. How many times and by how many different people does this need to be stated?

Comment: @GuillaumeF. for decades we where able to `stop()` or `suspend()` a `Thread`, also a "fundamental class" ... not anymore in Java 20 - `UnsupportedOperationException`!

Comment: @GuillaumeF Yes: To guarantee a value if  -1, 0 or 1, you have to wrap it with `Integer.signum( )`

Comment: @user207421 IntelliJ tells me I should use `Integer.compareTo()` to replace code that returns -1, 0, or 1 from a comparison (see edit to original post). If that's wrong, why is IntelliJ recommending that change?

Comment: @GuillaumeF. As per the comment in the answer, `Integer.compareTo()` is safe when integer overflow is possible, ie when `myInt` is a large negative number and `that.myInt` is a large positive number or visa versa such that `myInt - that.myInt` rolls under/over 2^31 (please read the linked article for a full explanation). When you know that this is not a possibility, for example if the range of values is not in the "large" range or values always have the same sign.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose they didn't specify it because the exact return value is completely irrelevant to the user. They kept it concise.

You rarely call that function yourself. It is mostly used to sort a list.

Also they can change it at any time (very unlikely but possible).